# where to Time out in java socket client program

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

I have below socket prog,i am able to successfully post test message to server prog,but sometime the process waits too long in case response is not received, can someone pls guide me on implementing time out and retry the same connection say after 2 secs.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Put_msg {
    public static String Post(String strRequestMessage, String strIP,
            int intPort) throws Exception {
        String strResponseMessage = "";
        try{
        Socket socket = null;
        socket = new Socket(strIP, intPort);
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(
                socket.getInputStream());

        PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        pw1.println(strRequestMessage);
        pw1.flush();

        strResponseMessage = readInputStream(bin);
        socket.close();
        socket = null;
        }catch(Exception e){
            strResponseMessage = "ERROR:Post_JAVA:"+e.toString();
            return strResponseMessage;
        }
        return strResponseMessage;
    }

    public static String readInputStream(BufferedInputStream in)
            throws Exception {
        String read_msg = "";

        int i = in.read();
        if (i == -1) {
            return "-1";
        }
        read_msg = read_msg + (char) i;
        int available = in.available();
        if (available > 0) {
            byte[] Data = new byte[available];
            in.read(Data);
            read_msg = read_msg + new String(Data);
        }
        return read_msg;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a timeout to the socket using the `setSoTimeout`:

```
socket = new Socket(strIp, intPort) ;
socket.setSoTimeout(2000); //2000 milliseconds
```

That'll timeout `read` calls that take longer than the time specified

Comment: Hi Vince, in my prog i have a socket instance with ip and port Socket socket = null;
        socket = new Socket(strIP, intPort); Is is possible to have another instance with same name ,also i have once more query will it retrigger the old instance in case of timeout

Comment: @Mani You would call that method using the instance you already have, not by creating a new instance. I'll edit my answer appropriatly

Answer (score 0):

Socket timeout a.k.a. `SO_TIMEOUT` will enable timeout on a blocking `read()` call, when you provide the `socket.setSoTimeout()` with a non-zero value (the default is zero, for no timeout).

However, a bigger problem with your code is using `available()`. I don't know what you're trying to do, but you're doing it wrong. Currently your code doesn't care if it receives from the other end anything, garbage, or the full amount of data. Why not read until the other end closes the connection to signal that all data was sent?

Comment: i have tried for a generic program .purpose of the code is to get any i/p msg and get a resp from server.server prog gets the req and based on the type of msg it sends the response back.

Comment: @Mani Then you'll want to define a proper protocol. Now you can get corrupt data back from the server, since you're using the `available()` method to read possibly only a part of the data.

Answer (score -1):

Set Socket timeout in the server or client socket like so:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
```

To repeat the attempt until it succeeds, put the code for initiating the connection in its own method, and have said method call itself from inside the method's catch statement. The catch statement is called every time there is a timeout, so you can recursively call the method from there until it succeeds.

Comment: Setting the socket to `new Socket()` in the server is pointless, and won't affect the read timeout of an accepted socket.